# Creating folder in Box using php

Tags: php, api, curl, box-api

I'm trying  to create a simple folder on Box, but I'm having a hard time. I keep getting this error:

> {"type":"error","status":404,"code":"not_found","help_url":"http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors","message":"Not Found","request_id":"71794126250a0c2f00fe35"}

here's my code:

```
$parent = array();
$parent['id'] = '0';
$params = array();
$params['name'] = 'Testfolder';
$params['parent'] = $parent;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: BoxAuth api_key={myAPIkey}&auth_token={myToken}"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

what is that i am missing.
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure parent folder exist ?

Comment: Didn't know that one, so the 2462th dropbox clone... Did you consider using ownCloud instead? It is open, free and can do much more than just hosting files for you: calendar, contacts, music, ... there are hundreds of free apps for that :-)

Comment: @GBD i am beginning with box today only..I wanted to create folder in root folder.I have read that root folder's id is always 0,hence i have given parent id as 0,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [BOX Docs](http://developers.box.com/docs/)

> By default, request body data is expected as JSON and response body
>   data is sent back as JSON.

```
$parent = array();
$parent['id'] = '0';
$params = array();
$params['name'] = 'Testfolder';
$params['parent'] = $parent;

$params = json_encode($params);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.box.com/2.0/folders");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($params), Authorization: BoxAuth api_key={myAPIkey}&auth_token={myToken}"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks mate..btw what is data_string,was getting undefined variable warning,hence removed it.Then the folder was created.

Comment: Thanks to point out this. it must be `strlen($params)` but it's optional

Comment: I think both 'content-type' and 'content-length' is optional,I removed both-its working fine.The main problem in my code was params,i sent it in array instead of json.Once again thanks..Cheerrzz!!!